# xcode storyboard controllers

Tags: xcode4

i am creating an application on xcode 4.3 and i have realized that if i add any view controllers to my storyboard file, yes i can add buttons and segues, but i can only connect thiese objects with my initial view controller, the one I had at the start. all the others can not connect to the codes. And if i connect an object to the codes on my initial view controller, and then just move in on another, it won't work. How can i fix this problem???

linking to codes i mean IBOutlets...

Comment: not sure what you're asking bud, care to expound more? perhaps add a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is because you didn't specify what is the CLASS of your View Controller.

To do this, select the View Controller (the one you can't "connect to code"), and in the column on the right, click on the Class drop-down menu and select the class where you have your code.

[image: Click on the drop down menu near Class]

Tell me if this arranges your problem !

Comment: actually, i still have the problem. I tried at first with one view controller and it worked, but not for the others. i am using only projectViewController.h for all the controllers

Comment: Oh okay... Unfortunately, I don't have another fast tip as the one I gave you before, and not enough information to help you more :/

Comment: oh, fixed. i just made a small error, your method worked, tks